# Проблема с software-center-aptdaemon-plugins python3-piston-mini-client после переустановки python3

Tags: linux

Удалил python3, попытался переустановить его, но получил ошибку:

> Следующие частично установленные пакеты будут настроены:
>   python3-piston-mini-client software-center-aptdaemon-plugins 
>   Ни одного пакета не будет установлено, обновлено или удалено.
>   0 пакетов обновлено, 0 установлено новых, 0 пакетов отмечено для удаления, и 4 пакетов не обновлено.
>   Необходимо получить 0 Б архивов. После распаковки 0 Б будет занято.
>   Настраивается пакет software-center-aptdaemon-plugins (0.1.6build1) …
>   /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center-aptdaemon-plugins.postinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center-aptdaemon-plugins.postinst: py3compile: not found
>   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета software-center-aptdaemon-plugins (--configure):
>    подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127
>   Настраивается пакет python3-piston-mini-client (0.7.5-0ubuntu2) …
>   /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-piston-mini-client.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-piston-mini-client.postinst: py3compile: not found
>   dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python3-piston-mini-client (--configure):
>    подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127
>   При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
>    software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
>    python3-piston-mini-client
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Пробовал :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo aptitude python3
```

К сожалению, ошибка возникает в любой команде перечисленной выше

Answer (score 0):

Ты походу грохнул питон от которого зависит часть пакетного менеджера. И чтобы поставить питон обратно - нужен пакетный менеджер, который (часть) написан на питоне. Классика `unzip.zip`. Если я прав - то выхода ровно 2:

1. Переустановка системы.
2. Докидывание файлов руками в систему. Т.е. скачиваем нужные `deb` на другом компе и через `mc` распаковаываем в родные каталоги.

Comment: Решил так, собрал питон из исходников, сделал ссылку на данный питон, обновился. Установил питон из репозитория, удалил старый.
**НИКОГДА НЕ УДАЛЯЙТЕ PYTHON**

Comment: Ну, частный случай 2-го пункта в принципе.